# How do you specify source in Google's measurement protocol transaction hits?

Tags: post, google-analytics, analytics, measurement-protocol

I've been able to send transaction hits to Google Analytics no problem through Hit Builder just to test out Hit Paylods. Link here: [Google's Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/)
Transactions are showing up in GA and their source is "Direct" on default it seems.

What I want is to specify source myself before sending out Transaction Hit. Like I would like to specify email instead of Direct, or specify one of the websites in (Other) Category. How would I go about that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the [cs (campaign source) parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cs). You may need to set other [traffic sources parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#trafficsources) for a working attribution (you should at least set "source" and "medium").

Comment: Oh, I can simply add `cs` parameter inside transaction hit? Do I need to somehow bundle it up with other kind of hits?

Comment: If you are doing Enhanced Ecommerce (which you should be) then the transaction data is bundled with a pageview in any case (instead of using a "transaction" hit). I have no idea whatsoever how the measurement protocol works with "classic" e-commerce tracking, but you should be okay if you send a pageview before the transaction with a source/medium attached with the same clientID.

Comment: Thanks, Apparently you can simply add one more parameter to classic "Transaction" hit and it works.